# color extract using bitwise >> in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, bit-manipulation

why is my alpha wrong?

```
var d:number = 0xff112233;

var r:number = (d & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
var g:number = (d & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
var b:number = d &  0x000000ff;
var a:number = (d & 0xff000000) >> 24 ;
console.log(r,g,b,a);
```

output:

17,34,51,**-0.00392156862745098**

Answer (score 4):

What you should use is a zero fill rightshift `>>>` instead of `>>` (signed propogating right shift) :

```
var d:number = 0xff112233;

var r:number = (d & 0x00ff0000) >>> 16;
var g:number = (d & 0x0000ff00) >>> 8;
var b:number = d &  0x000000ff;
var a:number = (d & 0xff000000) >>> 24 ;
console.log(r,g,b,a);
```

You get `17 34 51 255`

With `>>` you were only getting the right result when the most significant bit was `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running into inaccuracies in Javascript's number handling.

Shift first, then mask:

```
function extractRGBA(d) {
    var b = d & 0xFF;
    var g = (d >> 8) & 0xFF;
    var r = (d >> 16) & 0xFF;
    var a = (d >> 24) & 0xFF;
    return [r, g, b, a];
}

console.log(extractRGBA(0xff112233));

[17, 34, 51, 255]
```

Comment: I was messing around trying to find a solution, myself. That seems to be the answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/5s9e947e(v=vs.94).aspx

Bits shifter to the right are discarded and the signal bit is added to the left.

Answer (score 0):

may be try like this:
no need to use number specifically.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var d= 0xff112233;        
var r= (d & 0x00ff0000) >> 16 & 255;
var g= (d & 0x0000ff00) >> 8 & 255;
var b = d &  0x000000ff & 255;
var a= (d & 0xff000000) >> 24 & 255;
console.log(r,g,b,a);
});
```